# Why is Node.js Scaling Working on Linux, but not on Windows?

Tags: node.js, linux, windows

Learning Node and get stuck with this example:

```
// Adding child_process from the Node build-in Module:
let exec = require("child_process").exec;
// Requesting time:
let child = exec("uptime", function(err, stdout, stderr){
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error: " + stderr);
    } else {
      console.log("Output is: " + stdout);
    }
});
console.log("PID is: " + child.pid);
```

Can someone explain, why is this code running in Linux and not in Windows. Sorry, this may be a dumb question, but I am newbie and currently learning Node.
P.S. sorry if my question is not correct, I'm still getting used to post questions here. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think uptime is not windows command. It only works in Linux
You can use

```
systeminfo | find "Boot Time"
```

inplace of uptime. like

```
exec('systeminfo | find "Boot Time"')
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! It worked fine! And I don't know how to close this topic.. so...